# How to declare a column in datatables if its data is not in db?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have a datatable populated with data from database except from the last column that contains two buttons (edit/delete) generated for each record. I want to specify the columns inside `$("#myTable").DataTable` like this:

```js
columns: [
   { "data": "id" },
   { "data": "name" },
   { "data": "actions" },

]
```

But, since there doesn't exist an actions column in database I get an error when I do this. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: How do you get the data form the server? jQuery Ajax or DataTables built-in "remote source"?

Comment: I'm getting the data as json response from an ajax request . The response is an array of arrays like this `data
:
[["1", "John"], ["2", "Jim"]]`

Answer (score 4):

Set it to `null` instead of "actions" :

```
columns: [
   { data: "id" },
   { data: "name" },
   { data: null,
     render: function(data, type, full) {
       return '<button>Delete</button>'
     }
   }
]
```

Like in this example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/963/**